# Using Google Cloud Storage as central store for multi-instance Google Compute Engine

Tags: c++, mpi, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, boost-filesystem

I am using the Google Compute Engine to distribute simulation workload over multiple instances (machines) - all coded in C++ and using OpenMPI to parallelize calculations. Each 'remote' instance generates considerable data output that I now gather via MPI to the 'central' instance.

An alternative would be to directly store the data on a central location, e.g. Google Cloud Storage (GCS) from each instance, which would then need to handle considerable I/O. Yet I cannot find how to directly address the GCS buckets from within C++ (boost::filesystem) without using Google's gsutil. Hence the questions:

Is it possible to directly address Google's Cloud Storage buckets without using the gsutil and if so, how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`google-api-cpp-client`](https://github.com/google/google-api-cpp-client) to access all of Google APIs, including [Google Cloud Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/). That said, it would take some work to integrate it with `boost::filesystem` if that's your goal.